# Good, lightweight GUI-based process monitor for Linux

Tags: linux, display, process, gui, kill

I'd like a snappy **GUI-based** (I insist since people still want to propose console-based) application that can show me running processes and allow me to kill them, on Linux. It doesn't need to be as powerful as Window's Process Explorer or even Win7's Task Manager. Is there something lightweight and functional?

I'd appreciate a recommendation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So here is what I finally found, [LXTask](http://wiki.lxde.org/en/LXTask).

- Lightweight, simple
- Monitors processes
- Can kill processes
- Real GUI

[image]

There is also the GNOME system monitor, which also displays the process commandline. It is much more resource hungry though...

Comment: That *is* shiny. Don't forget to self select that as the answer when you can ;)

Comment: Will do. I wonder why I can't, and will I ever be able to do it that soon after a question?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work 48 hours minimum. I just tend to remind newish users cause answered/non selected questions tend to bounce back up, and i wanted to express that it *was* shiny, and i needed more words to get past the lameness filter ;p

Comment: Gnome System Monitor actually uses less memory than lxtask, ~10mb after opening compared to ~19mb for lxtask. Admittedly this is a few years after your Q/A so GSM will have improved while lxtask doesn't get updated much any more.

Answer (score 15):

Look at `htop`. It's light and it'll do what you want. Yes, it does launch in a console, but you can interact with it using the mouse, it's colored, it's live/animated, you can click on column headers to sort, scroll with the mouse, and anything else you care to try.

Comment: +1 for `htop` or for that matter `top`.

Comment: Its not gui, but htop is probably the *right* tool for the job. I think xkill is the best way to kill a graphical app on the other hand.

Comment: Who said it was an obsession? Who said it's specifically for me? This site is not for discussing what is asked.

Comment: Well, you can select the right answer. If people think its a good one, it'll still get upvoted. I'm still digging for something closer to your needs, but they all seem to be large DE specific things, or 200 years old.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: Thank you, but you don't need to dig further if you don't know one (I already googled before posting). I'm hoping someone has already adopted such a tool. Maybe I'll have to fallback on the gnome system monitor.

Comment: -1 for pointless soapboxing. +1 for offering a different option. -1 for that option not doing what the OP wanted (integrated ablity to kill processes)

Comment: @Wesley, press `k` in htop. It *does* have the ability to kill processes.

Comment: Maybe I need to write my question details with pink blinking letters ;)

Comment: the problem is i very distinctly remember one back in the day when i was running a custom ubuntu varient on an old box. I hardly used it, but it was there.

Comment: @fury: The thing is, in many similar cases people ask for GUIs not because they *need* GUIs but simply because they are deadly afraid of anything terminal-based even when all GUI alternatives suck; hence the htop suggestions.

Comment: @grawity: I understand, but it's not my case. However if I wanted a terminal-based app, there are plenty of solutions and I would not have come here.

Comment: @WesleyDavid not knowing that htop can kill doesn't mean htop can't kill. Fury: this site is *precisely* for discussing what was asked. And a command line GUI is still a GUI.

Comment: @Grawity I got confuzzled between `top` and `htop`

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi Yes, `htop` can kill a process. I got confused with `top` - however, concerning the word GUI - you keep using that word. I do not think it means what you think it means.

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi Well I've come to superuser because I knew stackoverflow and the way it works. Maybe it's different here, but in stackoverflow they insist on answering the questions and not questioning the questions. Sometimes the choice is justified and I am not asking for challenge in this post. Now coming back to your message, yes a command line GUI is still a GUI, but I feel that it's a play on words here considering how htop simulates a GUI.

Comment: @WesleyDavid curses/ncurses is as GUI as you can get without a window toolkit. That's globally accepted, and htop is written with ncurses.

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi Technically, yes, you are correct. However, you might need to reconsider your soft skills. On a site like SuperUser (or in any context in Meatspace), cultural context appears to have shifted quite some time ago. If someone asks for a "GUI Tool" in the 21st century, ncurses, while technically correct, is likely not a successful answer. I've removed my downvote (as if arbitrary numbers mean anything in real life). =)

Answer (score 10):

There's [Linux Process Explorer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/procexp/), a process management tool which seeks to mimic the functionality of Process Explorer for Windows.

Most GUI distros include a basic process management tool among their default system tool set.

Comment: I use CrunchBang Linux (Debian-based) and there is nothing but `top`. This distro lets users choose what they want :) Thank you for the link, looks interesting.

Comment: However it's 14MB and in python. Not lightweight, but looks powerful.

Comment: If you don't mind a terminal-only app then have a look at [htop](http://htop.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Thanks, but as stated in my question, for this app I would like a GUI.

Answer (score 2):

There is also [conky](http://conky.sourceforge.net/). It is not a process monitor, but system monitor which can show quite a lot of information about your system with quite many different themes. Plus it is light and done specifically for Linux. Additional themes you could download from [here](http://www.mediafire.com/download/5yb5ambg6h4jack/Deluxe_Conky_Theme_Pack.cmtp.7z).

Answer (score 1):

I like [MATE system monitor](https://github.com/mate-desktop/mate-system-monitor), it's a nice GUI with more versatility than GNOME system monitor.

Answer (score 0):

XFreq provides some Widgets to display the frequencies (including turbo boost), the temperatures, C-States and other features of the Intel Core i7 processors. It is also programmed for Core 2 and other Intel architectures.
http://code.google.com/p/xfreq