# Where do the variables of a new BASH shell come from?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, environment-variables

I am puzzled as about how environment variables work. From what I am aware, for a new process to have some environment variables, its parent must have issued `export`. But what about all the variables when we start a new bash session?

Demonstration:

```
manos@box:~$ bash
manos@box:~$ env
XDG_VTNR=7
SSH_AGENT_PID=2300
XDG_SESSION_ID=c2
..
```

Where does all this come from?

Answer (score 0):

The parent process in this case is your current shell. It loads some init scripts when it starts, they can export variables. Check `~/.bashrc`, `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `/etc/profile`.

It can also inherit some exported variables from its parent process back to the `init`.

Comment: I have checked these files and there is not a single line of code with `export`

Comment: The variables can be set without being exported.

Comment: Variables will also be inherited from the parent's environment (in Ubuntu, it's the `init` program). You can see which these are with the Linux Process Explorer - see http://superuser.com/questions/373692/good-lightweight-gui-based-process-monitor-for-linux.

Comment: Environment variables are by definition inherited by child processes. The three variables you show are probably set by your desktop environment.

Comment: The key point, it seems is that `export` exports to **all** descendants and not only the direct children as I initially thought. Oh and instead of process explorer you can simply use `pstree -p` :)